# PL/SQL concept with postgres, mysql, sqlite

Tags: sql

I am new to DB technologies. And now I have reached such concept as procedures and PL/SQL. As it is written it is a specific language added to Oracle SQL databases. Does it mean that this language is only available on Oracle DBs? And is not available on postgres, mysql and sqlite solutions?

Comment: (Almost) all databases have some scripting language that supports stored procedures.  The ideas are similar.  The syntax is different.

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL is indeed an Oracle specific language. However most databases have similar languages - SQL Server has [T-SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189826%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), Postgres has [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql.html), MySQL has [its own variant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines.html) (which doesn't seem to have a nifty name), etc.

The syntax of all these languages differ, but the concepts are similar.